# Problem rendering snow particles

Tags: rendering, particles

[image: you can see all detail in this image]

I made some snow particle; however, I can see the particle in the render preview but when I render, there are no particles. I checked and everything seems normal. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: check your render layers configuration

Comment: I voted to close as unclear what you are asking, as we do not have nearly enough information to go from. You will either have to upload a .blend or post your own answer if you have found it already.